# Dynamic V-model name in a v-for loop Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am developing an application and I am using Vue  and laravel , inside a v-for loop I need error.id in the loop to be bound to the v-model name of the elements, this my code:

```
 <tbody class="bodycol">
 <tr v-for="error in errors.error" :key="error.id" >

  <td>{{ error.client }}</td>
  <td>{{ error.session }}</td>
  <td>{{ error.info_session }}</td>
  <td>{{ error.UPROC }}</td>
  <td>{{ error.num_session }}</td>
  <td>{{ error.num_exec }}</td>
  <td>{{ error.date_debut }}</td>
  <td>{{ error.heure_debut }}</td>
  <td>{{ error.date_fin }}</td>
  <td>{{ error.heure_fin }}</td>
    <td>{{ error.status }}
    <form @submit="addComment(error.id)" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <input v-model="form.comment[error.id]" type="text" name="comment"
                  class="form-control area" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('comment') }" 
      required>
                  <has-error :form="form" field="comment"></has-error>
      </div>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
   data(){
  return{
   comment:[],
    }
     }
```

the problem is the output of the errors.status is:

```
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"the comment is here"]
```

Comment: your data is ```comment```, but not form ```{ comment: [] }```

Answer (score 2):

Change your data to this. You are referencing `form.comment` not `comment`

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                comment: []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it still the same output  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"the comment is here"]